# Only show specific content from a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some code that will go through a database and show the results in a table form (below).

I want to use this code, so that I can select a user and have the table update to show only information where the users name matches the one from the drop down:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="teamid">User</label>
        <?php
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT id, name FROM users');
echo "<select class='form-control' name='userid' id='userid'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
    </div>
```

**Original Code :**

```
 <table class= "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                       <tbody>
                                <th>User Name</td>
                                <th>Badge Name</th>
                                <th>Badge Level</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tr>                 
                        <?php
                $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT ub.id, users.name, individualbadges.badgename, ub.level
FROM userbadges ub
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id
INNER JOIN individualbadges ON individualbadges.id = ub.badge_id') or die(mysqli_error($connection));
                        $i=0;
                        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            if($i%2==0) $class = 'even'; else $class = 'odd';

                            echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">
<th id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name"><span>'.$fetch['name'].'</span></th>

<td id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="BadgeName"><span>'.$fetch['badgename'].'</span></td>

<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="level" data-type="text" data-title="New Badge Level (0,1,2,3)"><span>'.$fetch['level'].'</span></td>

                            </tr>';                         
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is this just basic SQL - add a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the condition to select the particular user by

> WHERE `username` = `$name`

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ub.id, users.name, individualbadges.badgename, ub.level
FROM userbadges ub
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id
INNER JOIN individualbadges ON individualbadges.id = ub.badge_id where `username`='$name'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: doesn't work - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: make sure you has `username` and '$name'. for example i use  `username`='$name' for the code

Comment: You're closing your string at `= ub.badge_id'` - remove that quote. Also remove the the opening single quote at `'SELECT`. Then enclose the entire query in double quotes (`"`). Variables are only expanded in double quote strings, not single quotes.

Comment: I updated the code. thanks for remember @Eborbob. I forget to remove the single quotes.

Comment: How would I make it show all everything and not just a single user?

Comment: @Unknown , yes but I want it to show everything if nothing is selected

Comment: Then put it in **if condtion** like `if($name==""){//your query 'without' where condition} else {your query 'with' where condition}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following

1. Add on-change event for the select box and post back selected `user_id`
2. Get the `user_id` from `$_REQUEST`

> $user_id = $_REQUEST['userid'];

3. Change your query like this:

> $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT ub.id, users.name,
>   individualbadges.badgename, ub.level
>       FROM userbadges ub
>       INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id
>       INNER JOIN individualbadges ON individualbadges.id = ub.badge_id where users.id = '. $user_id) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

**Edited code**

Assign your sql to a PHP variable

> $sql = 'SELECT ub.id, users.name,
>   individualbadges.badgename, ub.level
>       FROM userbadges ub
>       INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id
>       INNER JOIN individualbadges ON individualbadges.id = ub.badge_id';

Check whether $user_id is set or not

```
if(isset($user_id))
{
    $sql .= "WHERE users.id = '. $user_id;
}
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

So, Your entire code will look something like this:

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['userid'];

$sql = 'SELECT ub.id, users.name, individualbadges.badgename, ub.level FROM userbadges ub INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id INNER JOIN individualbadges ON individualbadges.id = ub.badge_id';

if(isset($user_id))
{
     $sql .= "WHERE users.id = '. $user_id;
}
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: @Jess You need to show all the names even though the selected username is something else? Your requirement is confusing.

Comment: Yes. Its all shown unless you choose a specific name

Comment: where would the if statement go?

Comment: It should be after $sql statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80973/discussion-between-rads-and-jess).